# Property of a basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

**Definition.**
A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is called a *basis*  for a topology on $X$ if

(1) for each $x\in X$, there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$,

(2) if $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

I want to show the second condition extends to finitely many $B's$. In other words, I want to show that if $B_1, \ldots, B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$, then there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$.

*proof.*

The case $n=1$ is obvious.

Suppose $B_1, \ldots, B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$ implies that there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$. Let $B_1, \ldots, B_n, B_{n+1} \in \mathcal{B}$ and let $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}B_i=\bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i \cap B_{n+1}$. Then by the induction hypothesis, there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i$. We have $x\in B\cap B_n$, where $B, B_n\in\mathcal{B}$. Thus, by (2), there exists $B'\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B' \subset B \cap B_n \subset\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}B_i$. Q.E.D.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It is correct. Do you see why the intersection of n-many $B_i$'s is again in the topology?If you have not proved it before in order to use it here, you may need to prove it in this proof.

Comment: @AksharaPrasad Where am I assuming the intersection of $n$ many $B_i$'s is in the topology?

Comment: You don't, and that's OK since you showed it through induction. What @AksharaPrasad probably means is that the statement you showed here *doesn't add anything significantly new* to the definition.

Comment: ^ In the sense that if you know for any $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ that $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, then you have for any $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ that $B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \dots \cap B_n \in \mathcal{B}$.